Looking for a children's story from the 1950s about a little girl that sews a clown
I read a story as a child about a little girl named Janie with red hair. Her mother and she sewed a clown out of scraps of material. Would anyone remember this story?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you misremember the name, it could be "Jingle Bell Jack" by Miss Francis (Frances R. Horwich).
From the Kirkus review:

A make-it-at-home story takes Jean and her mother through an enjoyable
project- sewing a toy clown out of different scraps of colorful
material.

